# De-serializing Duration Member In Data Class Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, deserialization, duration

I have a data class like below that has a member of type **Duration**:

```
@Serializable
data class DataClass(
    val fieldOne: Long,
    val fieldTwo: String,
    val fieldThree: Duration,
) {
    constructor() : this(0, "", Duration.ZERO, "")
}
```

I am working with Firebase Realtime Database to store this DataClass and am encountering an issue when I de-serialize a DataClass object.

I am seeing that even though the value held in fieldThree gets stored appropriately in Firebase Realtime Database, when de-serializing it in the application, the value is zero (0).

This happens because of the default constructor in place and I don't understand why.

I need the default constructor or else I will get an error while de-serializing stating that a default constructor is missing from the DataClass.

I am aware that I need **Kotlin 1.7.20** to be able to serialize a Duration object (reference [here](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/issues/1472)) and have done so in my application. I have also tried implementing the custom serializer suggested in the reference above.

All other fields are de-serialized correctly, no matter the value.

An example of an instantiation of the DataClass can be:

```
DataClass(12345, "", Duration.hours(1))
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firebase Realtime Database can only store JSON values.

The [Kotlin `Duration` class](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.time/-duration/) is not a known [JSON type](https://www.json.org/json-en.html), and a quick [code search on the SDK](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Afirebase%2Ffirebase-android-sdk+path%3A%2F%5Efirebase-database%5C%2F%2F+Duration&type=code) doesn't show any special handling for the type.

In order to store a duration in the Firebase Realtime Database, you'll have to keep it as a supported JSON type in your data class, or handle the conversions yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply @Frank van Puffelen. Could you elaborate a bit on your suggestions? Because I have tried handling the serialization/de-serialization of the Duration field, but that did not seem to work.

Comment: If I recall correct, this is where the SDK handles its mapping between Java/Kotlin classes and the JSON in the database: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/blob/master/firebase-database/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/database/core/utilities/encoding/CustomClassMapper.java#L48. Fair warning: this is quite involved, so you may want to consider whether you're not better off storing the duration in a JSON type that Firebase supports natively.